# Excel calculating status based on status of multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a table with a lot of columns but I am focusing on four columns (I have a picture below).  Three of the columns are hierarchical milestones/tasks to be done in that column/milestone 3 is a subset of column 2 and column 2 is a subset of one.  The last column is a status column with at risk, on track, complete, etc.

I need to pull the columns so that I only see column 1 and two and the status column (eliminating individual tasks).  However, I want the status to have a logical formula stating if any of the tasks are at risk, all of its group (column 2) is at risk even if other subsets are on track.  Please see photo below!

[Excel Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF0gw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the solution you asked for, but have you considered the following layout. Place `Status` column to columns section in pivot table and aggregate by count:

[image]

Now you can see number of tasks of each status for each milestone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I have understood it correctly, but you may want to take a look at array formulas, something like this:

```
{=sum(IF(A1:A20="some criteria",if(B1:B20="other criteria", if(C1:C20="At risk",1,0),0),0)}
```

But honestly, I am a bit confused of what you really want to achieve.

Comment: The {} around the functions mean array formulas, you should not type it in, but press ctrl+shift+enter after you finished the formula.